# Remove CV type qualifiers from libclang's CXType

Tags: libclang

I use libclang to parse source file and get reference to some type as `CXType`, say it is "`const std::__1::basic_string<char>`" (as reported by  `clang_getTypeSpelling`). How can I get reference to same type but without const qualifier?

Comment: Same problem here. need to walk from a const CXType to its corresponding non const

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by visiting the type's cursor's children.  For example, given a CXCursor 'cursor',

```
CXType type = clang_getCursorType(cursor);
if (clang_isConstQualifiedType(type))
{
    auto RemoveConstFromType = [](CXCursor c, CXCursor, CXClientData d)
    {
        *(CXType*)d = clang_getCursorType(c);
        return (clang_isConstQualifiedType(*(CXType*)d) ? CXChildVisit_Recurse : CXChildVisit_Break);
    };
    clang_visitChildren(cursor, RemoveConstFromType, &type);
}
```

I hope that helps. =)